# Adding include files information to library in CMake

Tags: include, cmake, libraries

I'd like to use imported and internal libraries in my CMake projects so that the projects don't need to know the details of the library. (By "Internal library" I mean other CMake library targets, not sure about the correct term...)

The information should contain:

- library locations for each configuration type (including dll's and .pdb files)
- library include files folder

In some project I'd like to write something like:

```
 SET(TARGET_DEPENDS ext_lib1 ext_lib2 internal_lib1)
```

and let the build system take care of all the include folder and configuration stuff.

What is the best way to achieve this?

AFAIK the `add_library(... IMPORTED)` supports pretty much everything else, but the include folder information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building your "internal" library, you could also prepare a `YourInternalLibraryConfig.cmake` file which prepares all those things a user would need to "import" the library.

This `YourInternalLibraryConfig.cmake` needs to be created when building the internal library or when installing it.

In this `YourInternalLibraryConfig.cmake`, it should call `add_library( YourInternalLibrary IMPORTED )` and make sure all the properties have been correctly prepared. E.g. it can prepare

- a `YourInternalLibrary_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable with the necessary include-dirs.
- a `YourInternalLibrary_DEFINES` with the required compiler-defines
- a `YourInternalLibrary_LIBRARIES` summarizing **all** the libraries provided

That way a user (e.g. the main app ) of your internal library can simply call:

```
find_package( YourInternalLibrary )
include_directories( ${YourInternalLibrary_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_definitions( ${YourInternalLibrary_DEFINES} )
target_link_library( main ${YourInternalLibrary_LIBRARIES} )
```

For more complex projects you could choose to generate a separate `UseYourInternalLibrary.cmake` which does these three steps for you, optionally with switches enabling/disabling certain parts of your internal.

For some good examples take a look at the sources for [Vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) or [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Vtk and OpenCV were good references. We've been stuck to VS2008 projects with lots of .vsprops files and moving to another build system has been a big pain. CMake frees us to use any build system we want. Pretty amazing!